# Get request with ajax throw a 403 error in localhost but not in a web server

Tags: php, ajax, localhost

The thing is that I download my code from my webserver because I need to make some test but when I tried to acces a route with ajax it doesn't let me, here is part of my code:

```
function ajaxFunction(id){
   // Para incompatibilidades
   try{
      // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

   }catch (e){

      // Internet Explorer Browsers
      try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

      }catch (e) {
         try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
         }
      }
   }


   // Here processRequest() is the callback function.
   ajaxId = id;

   switch (ajaxId) {

     case 1:
       data = document.getElementById('selectFinca').value;
       extraUrl = "finca_id=" + data;
       break;

     case 2:
       data = document.getElementById('selectFincaDesk').value;
       extraUrl = "finca_id=" + data;
      break;
   }
   ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = endAjax;
   var url = "https://localhost/dev/ajax/out.php?ajaxId=" + ajaxId + "&" + extraUrl;
   ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
   ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

All that I need is to send ajaxId and finca_id to out.php but this error is trown:

```
GET https://localhost/dev/ajax/out.php?ajaxId=2&finca_id=24 403 (Forbidden)
```

the thing is that the exactly same code it is working online.

Comment: It would help to provide the content of out.php as there can be number of reasons for it to throw error 403. Also try opening https://localhost/dev/ajax/out.php?ajaxId=2&finca_id=24 directly in browser and check the output - you may get a clue for the reason of the error.

Comment: Could it be that you're requesting it as HTTPS and you obviously don't have a certificate for HTTPS on local host. Try with HTTP.

Comment: @Abraham that was the problem, but can yo explain a little bit about it please?

Comment: @JorgeIvanAguirre if your using xampp on your testing environment you can learn with this link https://www.adam.co.za/setup-https-in-xampp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP and HTTPS are two protocols to make a request to a server. There's others, but for websites these are the two commonly used.

When you make a request using HTTPS the browser attempts to make a secure connection using an SSL certificate. You were getting a 403 forbidden error because you obviously don't have an SSL certificate on your local machine.

Some JavaScript APIs require HTTPS like Geo location and browser notifications and will fail if they are used without a secure connection. Though they can be tested on local host just fine.

HTTP is just a regular unsecured connection and you should expect that data you pass through here can be seen by anyone. You would not want to pass credit card data or personal information without at the very least having and SSL certification.

You'll sometimes see links leaving out the protocol on CSS of JS libraries like this:
//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Leaving out the protocol and loading in an asset like this just tells the browser to use whatever protocol it is currently using so that if you develop an site on HTTP and then you go to HTTPS, your HTTPS connection won't break from trying to load assets over HTTP.

Else you would have to go and update every place something is being loaded in as HTTP so your HTTPS connection doesn't break.

Hope that helps.